# React-Bootstrap input text lose focus when opened from a OverlayTrigger in a Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a button in a modal that on click opens a popover component, in the popover I have an input text field.

The problem I have is that the input lose focus instantly, I can't type in it because something else is hijacking the focus out of it and I can't figure out what is, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dew-owd801?file=/src/App.js) is a working example of the problem.

And here is the code in question:

```js
import "./styles.css";

import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, OverlayTrigger, Popover, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const popover = (
    <Popover id="popover-basic">
      <Popover.Content>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter value"
        />
      </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Fragment>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
          Open
        </Button>

        {showModal && (
          <Modal
            show={showModal}
            onHide={() => setShowModal(false)}
            centered
            backdrop="static"
            animation={false}
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>modal</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <p>Hello</p>

              <OverlayTrigger
                trigger="click"
                placement="right"
                overlay={popover}
              >
                <Button variant="secondary">Open Popover</Button>
              </OverlayTrigger>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it only loosong focus in a modal? What if you only use a button with an Overlay?

Comment: Yes in the modal there is a problem, just the button and overlay works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modal has a property "enforceFocus", which keeps focus on the Modal component. The property value is set to true per default. Set it to false and you will be able to use your input.

"https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/modal/#modal-props

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the enforceFocus works, but I'm not sure it is the best alternative. If the user navigates the fields using the tab key, he might focus elements outside of the modal, which could create confusion.

Instead, I suggest you play with the [overlay's container prop](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/overlays/#overlay-props). You could use a ref to the modal itself, or to a container inside the modal. This way, the overlay will be "inside" the modal and won't lose focus.

I created an [example to demonstrate it works](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boostrap-modal-overlay-bm2rdb?file=/src/App.js).